# JNDI lookup of web service fails in Websphere web application

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, jndi

I am trying to call a SAP web Service from within a web application running on Websphere 7.

A client was generated from a WSDL and I use a JNDI lookup to find the service. The lookup fails with a `NameNotFoundException`.

web.xml:

```
<service-ref>
    <description>
    WSDL Service ZSDWebAddressPrinting</description>
    <service-ref-name>service/ZSDWebAddressPrinting</service-ref-name>
    <service-interface>sap_com.document.sap.soap.functions.mc_style.ZSDWebAddressPrinting_Service</service-interface>
    <wsdl-file>WEB-INF/wsdl/ZSDWebAddressPrinting.wsdl</wsdl-file>
    <jaxrpc-mapping-file>WEB-INF/ZSDWebAddressPrinting_mapping.xml</jaxrpc-mapping-file>
    <service-qname xmlns:pfx="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
    pfx:ZSDWebAddressPrinting</service-qname>
    <port-component-ref>
        <service-endpoint-interface>sap_com.document.sap.soap.functions.mc_style.ZSDWebAddressPrinting_PortType</service-endpoint-interface>
    </port-component-ref>
</service-ref>
```

JNDI lookup:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
return (Service)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/service/ZSDWebAddressPrinting");
```

Exception:

```
[10.12.14 10:24:03:645 CET] 00000024 SystemOut     O |2014-12-10 10:24:03,645|ERROR|r : 0|ws.WebServiceLocator.getService - Lookup of service reference with jndi name =  ZSDWebAddressPrinting failed !
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/service not found in context "java:".
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1837)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1166)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1095)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:221)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.acme.ws.WebServiceLocator.getService(WebServiceLocator.java:26)
```

I have used `dumpnamespace` to show all the names but I cannot see `ZSDWebAddressPrinting`.

There are a number of JDBC resources which are also accessed via JNDI. These are visible in the dump and work fine.

Am I forgetting something here?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the class loading from `PARENT_LAST` to `PARENT_FIRST` helped. The service lookup now works.

I have no idea why this makes a difference to JNDI. The JDBC lookup works in both cases.

Can anyone comment on this?